# Bypassing google play store region lock

Tags: google-play-store

I am from Slovakia and am going to be in Germany for the next couple of months which is why I purchased a german SIM card and I now want to download their region locked app. I find the google play rules understandable, but also draconian and cannot really afford the penalty of changing the account's region through official means in the play store (you can only change the region once a year, you can lose your current region apps &c). I know creating a new account is a solution, what else? Trying out some payment method glitches is out of question (it's a cat&mouse game).

**TLTR:
With the presumption of full control over the system (capable of rooting) what can be done to install any google play region blocked app?**

Are there any reputable google play "mirrors"? Also, couldn't google start ditching these rules implemented for the big telephone operator or for the propietary content sharing company in the case of DRM, when the userbase of their services is now almost assured.

Comment: Are you sure you need that? To my knowledge the number of region locked apps isn't very high. So I would first try it without changing the region. And app prices should be higher in Germany compared to your home region.

Comment: I need to check the balance of the card, so yes.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. There's no way other than changing the Play Store country and using their payment once, even on rooted devices. As for Google's decision, unfortunately that's out of topic because we are not affiliated with them and don't know their internal policy.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create another google email/account and set it's county to Germany.

Note that some of the region locked may not work when you are back home. Some require a VPN as well as the account of the right country.

I have a few accounts myself, for this purpose.